# Collect only keys for values of a certain type from a collection

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For instance let's say we have

```
type AnObject = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: string
  d: number
}

type ExtractKeysOfType<O extends {[K: string]: any}, T> = ///...

type StringKeys = ExtractKeysOfType<AnObject, string> // 'a' | 'c'
```

Is they're a way to achieve `ExtractKeysOfType` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mapped types combined with conditional types here:

```
type ExtractKeysOfType<T, Target> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Target ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```

This essentially works by going over each key in type T. Does `T[K]` extend our Target type? if so, great, and the property value is simply that Key. If not, that key has type `never`.

This intermediary type, for your case, looks like:

```
{
    a: "a";
    b: never;
    c: "c";
    d: never;
}
```

Then, that intermediary type is indexed again by keys of T. This will produce your desired union, since the `never` types are ignored by the compiler here.

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgeQEYCsIGNhQLxQN4BQUUAhgFxQDOwATgJZwDmRUSFcArgLZIQ0voK1ekxYATdt178AvgQKhIUAKIAPWiUwBpCCEoIAZgBVwEADxGANFCMkajCMAB8OfCwDaWqAygBrXQD2BjYAuhRGniFQEOoQcGKUNnYOWAD8UF7sEABufAQy7v4gQaEA3PIKplAAyrQMjDp6rmoa2rr6xqZm8MhomNbC9S4A9MNQAOQk41AAPhPo40A)