# Howto extract only async function from type/interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given a utility `ExtractKeysOfType` that allows to retrieve only key of a type/interface that match a target and the `Pick` type i can easily extract function from a given type/interface.
What I want to accomplish is to extract only the async function (and not all signatures) from the base type.

Any clue on how to achieve that ?

```
type ExtractKeysOfType<T, Target> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Target ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type Type = {
  prop: boolean
  fn (): boolean
  fn (): Promise<boolean>
}

type OnlyFunc = Pick<
  Type,
  ExtractKeysOfType<Type, (...as: any) => any>
> // {fn (): {boolean; Promise<boolean>}

type OnlyAsync = ??? // Someway to build type such as OnlyAsync: {fn (): Promise<boolean>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397693/14357) as inspiration, we can define an `OnlyAsync` type using [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) types as follows:

```
// finds keys of Promise returning function members
type PromiseFuncKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => Promise<any>) ? K : never;
}[keyof T]
// so we can Pick them
type OnlyAsync<T> = Pick<T, PromiseFuncKeys<T>>;
```

Here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59256857/14357) that should shed some light on what's going on here.

Comment: I've tried it but it extracts all functions
The issue here is that function have the same names so by picking names nad then `Pick` on same we do get all function definitions not only the async ones  
The linked answer is the definition provided on my question (and a question I did ask a while ago ^^)